# Removing the first element from a list, and appending that element to another list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, append

As the title states, I have four separate lists. What I want to be able to do is this:

```
/* Pseudo-code (not in prolog).. */
if(size(List1) % 2 == 1) {
    /* Take the head of List1, and move it to List2 */
}
if(size(List2) % 2 == 1) {
    /* Take the head of List2, and move it to List3 */
}
if(size(List4) % 2 == 1) {
    /* Take the head of List4 and move it to List2 */
}
if(size(List3) % 2 == 1) {
    /* Take the head of List3 and move it to List4 */
}
```

So, if I have this format: `list(contents, list_name)`
and the following facts:

```
list([1,2,3,4], List1).
list([5,6,7], List2).
list([8,9,10], List3).
list([11,12,13,14], List4).

% validList(ListNo,ListTransfer).
% If ListNo has an odd number of items, we can move any item to the list, ListTransfer).
validList(List1,List2).
validList(List2,List3).
validList(List2,List4).
validList(List4,List3).
```

I wrote this to check it, but I'm not sure I'm on the right path:

```
checkList(ListFrom,ListTo):-
    1 is mod(size(ListFrom), 2), % Check to see if size of list is odd
    ListFrom = [Head|Tail],      % it is, so we grab the head of the list
    append(Head, ListTo, ListTo).% we then append it to the correct list
```

I'm extremely new to prolog and am still trying to wrap my head around it. Is there a more concise way to code this shifting of a list item depending on certain constraints?

Comment: What does a *list modulo 2* mean (referring to your pseudo code)?

Comment: What does, for example, *move it to list2* mean? To the head of list2? The end? And you start by saying *I have two separate lists* but your pseudo-code indicates four.

Comment: Some of the comments (e.g., `/* Take the head of List2 and move it to List4 */`) appears to be wrong. Please clearify their validity or edit your question and correct them.

Comment: @lurker Sorry, updated it again. I meant move it anywhere within the specific list. I will be re-sorting the lists later on.

Comment: @repeat Sorry about that, I updated to reflect what list I want to correctly move each value to.

Comment: By *move it anywhere* then you want to generate all possible solutions for each case of where it goes in the list? Note that in Prolog, `list([1,2,3], Foo).` doesn't assign the list to the variable `Foo`. `Foo` remains uninstantiated. You can "label" the list with an atom if you wish, like `list([1,2,3], foo).`

Comment: @lurker Lets say I have list1 with an odd number of values, i want to move one item from list1 to the end of list2 (theoretically I could move it anywhere and it wouldn't matter to me, but for the sake of argument ill just move it to the end). When I look at list1 this item should no longer be present and when I look at list2 I should see the item that was previously in list1 somewhere in the list.

Comment: OK I think I follow that. You just care that it goes into the list somewhere. Now about your sample Prolog code, it's got fundamental issues that tell me you haven't looked up the valid way to do certain things in Prolog. For example, you can't get the size of a list with, `size(MyList)`. `append(Head, ListTo, ListTo)` will fail because it says that `ListTo` is what you get when you append `Head` to `ListTo` (which obviously can't be true - `ListTo` can't be itself, and itself with `Head` prepended at the same time). Not to mention, `Head` isn't a list, and `append` requires list arguments.

Comment: Are the items supposed to go in circles? List2 to List3 to List4 and back to List2?!

Comment: @repeat Sort of? Basically, I know for a fact that at the end (after moving items around if there are an odd amount of items), that each list will have an even amount of items.

Comment: @lurker Sorry about that. This is just a small part of an assignment for a class I'm in. We had one lecture total on prolog and our teacher told us to use `size(MyList)` to determine the size of the list. She also gave us that append definition because "it will help out." I was just writing it down from her notes. :/ I would appreciate any help on this issue though.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** The two pseudo codes you give in the OP do not match!

---

The following is based on two assumptions:

1. A fixed point is to be reached. After all, you wrote in one of your comments:

   > Basically, I know for a fact that at the end (after moving items around if there are an odd amount of items), that **each list will have an even amount of items**.
2. The **first** pseudo code is what you are aiming for.

   ```
   /* Pseudo-code (not in prolog).. */
   if(size(List1) % 2 == 1) {
       /* Take the head of List1, and move it to List2 */
   }
   if(size(List2) % 2 == 1) {
       /* Take the head of List2, and move it to List3 */
   }
   if(size(List4) % 2 == 1) {
       /* Take the head of List4 and move it to List2 */

   if(size(List3) % 2 == 1) {
       /* Take the head of List3 and move it to List4 */
   }
   ```

**Bad news:** Above "code" may not reach a fixed point (that fulfills the first constraint)!

As a counterexample consider the following cycle (`2->3->4->2`):

1. `L1 = [], L2 = [2], L3 =  [], L4 =  []`: Take the head of L2, and move it to L3
2. `L1 = [], L2 =  [], L3 = [2], L4 =  []`: Take the head of L3 and move it to L4
3. `L1 = [], L2 =  [], L3 =  [], L4 = [2]`: Take the head of L4 and move it to L2
4. `L1 = [], L2 = [2], L3 =  [], L4 =  []`: go back to step 1